# Tell waf to wait for task to finish before staring next task

Tags: python, waf

I have two Tasks in `waf` and they need to be exectued in the correct order, and the second task, has to wait until the first task has finished.

To show that it's behaving the way I expected it to work, I wait inside the tasks, in the first task (`t_1`) **4** seconds and in the second task (`t_2`) **1** second. And the second task finishes first. This can be seen, as the folders I create after waiting have timestamps `t_2 < t_1`.

In one Question:
**How can I tell waf, that `t_2` is exectued after `t_1` finished successfully?**

---

1. MWE: **wscript**

   ```
   from waflib import Context, Options
   from waflib import Task, TaskGen
   from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler

   def options(opt):
       opt.load('compiler_c')

   def configure(cnf):
       cnf.load('compiler_c')

   def build(bld):
       bld.program(features=['t_1', 't_2'], source='main.c', target='abc')

   class t_1(Task.Task):
       always_run = True
       run_str = 'echo start t_1 && python -c "import time; time.sleep(4)" && echo end t_1 && mkdir t_1'
       color = 'RED'


   @TaskGen.feature('t_1')
   @TaskGen.after('apply_link')
   @TaskGen.before('t_2')
   def add_t_1_task(self):
       self.create_task('t_1')


   class t_2(Task.Task):
       always_run = True
       run_str = 'echo start t_2 && python -c "import time; time.sleep(1)" && echo end t_2 && mkdir t_2'
       color = 'RED'


   @TaskGen.feature('t_2')
   @TaskGen.after('apply_link', 't_1')
   def add_t_2_task(self):
       self.create_task('t_2')
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the task which has to run **before** (in that example `t_1`) in `after` attribute of the task which should "**wait**" for the the other task to finish (in that example (`t_2`).
It is specified like this: `after = ['t_1']`

The documentation to this can be found here in section [build order constraints](https://waf.io/book/#_build_order_constraints) in the [waf book](https://waf.io/book/).

The documentation that explains [generic task generator is §9.3](https://waf.io/book/#_general_purpose_task_generators) in the current waf book (waf 2.0), especially §9.3.4 explains the task generator execution order.

---

The complete example MWE looks then like this:

```
from waflib import Context, Options
from waflib import Task, TaskGen
from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
    bld.program(features=['t_1', 't_2'], source='main.c', target='abc')

class t_1(Task.Task):
    always_run = True
    run_str = 'date && echo 1 && echo start t_1 && python -c "import time; time.sleep(4)" && echo end t_1 && mkdir t_1 && date && echo 1'
    color = 'RED'


@TaskGen.feature('t_1')
@TaskGen.after('apply_link')
@TaskGen.before('t_2')
def add_t_1_task(self):
    self.create_task('t_1')


class t_2(Task.Task):
    always_run = True
    after = ['t_1'] # <---------------------------- **The problems solution**
    run_str = 'date && echo 1 && echo start t_2 && python -c "import time; time.sleep(1)" && echo end t_2 && mkdir t_2 && date && echo 2'
    color = 'RED'


@TaskGen.feature('t_2')
@TaskGen.after('apply_link', 't_1')
def add_t_2_task(self):
    self.create_task('t_2')
```

Comment: `@TaskGen.before('t_2')` is wrong. It shoul be `@TaskGen.before('add_t_2_task')`. Moreover it is not necessary. Tasks `t_1` and `t_2` can be created in any order in your example. What is important is the execution order.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Where can I find the documentation, that I need to put the task generator methods not tasks as constraint? But my solution to the problem of using `after = ['t_1']` in `class t_2(Task.Task):` is correct?

Comment: @neuro sorry for asking again, but as you seem very experienced with waf, I would very much appriciate if you would tell me, where to find this in the documentation?

Comment: I added the reference for task method execution order, ie §9.3.4 in current waf book. §9.3.6 might be of interest too, it explains how to set abstract dependencies between taskgens.

Comment: Thanks for updating your already perfect answer - I have already read these section, but it seems I have missed something to fully understand, and therefore I will read it again!